# Are bitwise operations portable?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, bitwise-operators

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int j = -1 & 0xFF;
```

The resulting value in `j` could be one of the following based on the underlying representation:

```
    System          Value
Two's complement    0xFF
One's complement    0xFE
Sign/Magnitude      0x01
```

But are the `&`, `|`, and `^` operators in C always defined in terms of two's complement (thus making `j` always be equal to `0xFF`), or are they defined in terms of the underlying representation of the system?

Comment: As a general advice, using signed integers should be avoided for bit-ops as well as the left operand of bitshifts (the right operand hardly can be large enough to cause trouble).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're defined in terms of the actual bit representation. From the [C11 final draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.10):

> The result of the binary & operator is the bitwise AND of the operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if each of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).
>   ...
>   The result of the ^ operator is the bitwise exclusive OR of the operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if exactly one of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).
>   ...
>   The result of the | operator is the bitwise inclusive OR of the operands (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only if at least one of the corresponding bits in the converted operands is set).

Comment: So even a quantum processor must obey this for its registers? Of course for all dimensions of qubits?

Comment: So it must be that only non-negative bitwise operations are portable.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Programming a quantum processor in a classical programming language does not make sense - iff it was possible at all. But if you want to call this standard compliant, of course it had to. That's the basic idea behind **any** standard. Calling a screw compliant to ISO4032 of course also implies certain properties.

Comment: Note that regardless of representation, the resulr of casting -1 to an unsigned integer type is always the largest representable value in that type, which must be 2**k-1 for some integer k. However, the cast needs to be explicit; the integer promotions will not automatically convert signed to unsigned.